# Opening an alert outside of the popup window in a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension I am writing where I have a button on the popup page, that when pressed should open an alert with a little help text for the user. I can get the alert to appear in the popup window by calling:

```
var button = document.getElementById("HelpMe");
button.addEvenListener("click", function(){
    alert("HelpText");
});
```

But this opens the alert in the popup window, which puts it mostly offscreen. I want to make the alert appear in the main tab, which would put the alert right in the center of the screen.

I tried this:

```
var button = document.getElementById("HelpMe");
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code:`
        alert("HelpText");
        `
    });
});
```

But it didn't seem to do anything, and I can't get any error messages or logs to appear that I have been able to find. Advice is appreciated.

Comment: The popup is a separate window so it has separate devtools: rightclick the popup, click "Inspect", and check the console for errors. It's likely you don't have the necessary permissions in manifest.json - in this case it's `"activeTab"`.

Comment: I do have the activeTab permission set in the Manifest. There are no warnings/errors in the console for the popup either.

Comment: Well, then your code is correct. It works here. Apparently there's something else you're not telling us. Try to make an [MCVE](/help/mcve), otherwise I doubt anyone could guess the answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Apparently the thing I wasn't saying was that in my real HelpText, there was a newline. Removing the newline fixed everything. Not sure why that did it, but it works now. Thanks for your advice!